# 502 Bad Gateway error when i try to launch neural network modeller canvas from IBM Watson studio?

Tags: data-science-experience, watson-studio

I am using Neural Network Modeller Beta version and consistently get 502 bad getaway error when i try to launch the modeller flow. Please advise whether it is a known issue and whether there's a fix.

Answer (score 1):

502 indicates a problem on the server side. You should report that directly to IBM support, so that somebody there has a look, if the problem isn't resolved automatically after some time.

Stack Overflow is better suited for questions around programming Watson Studio, rather than operational problems there.

Comment: Thanks Roland. I will do that. I was advised to check with the Stack overflow community for the same.